# Writing shareable method in Angular Services

Tags: angular

In my component1.ts I have

```
 ngOnInit(){this.query= "some text"; this.getProjectList(this.query);}

 public getProjectList(query: object) {
    this.appservice.search(this.query).then((response: any) => {
      if (response) {
        this.projects = response.results;
      }
    });
  }
```

I need to write same function with different query parameter in component2.ts

So instead of writing same function again n again. I am trying to write sharable service for that but stuck in between.

```
@Injectable()
export class ProjectService { 
constructor(private appService: AppService){}

getProjectList(query: object) {
    this.appService.search(query).then((response: any) => { // query param here need to updated

      if (response) {
        return response.results;?? // I don't know what should I write here

      }
    });
  }


}
```

Please let me know how can I update the above method in sharable service and consume it in component1.ts and component2.ts

Answer (score 0):

you can use switchMap. Something like that:

```js
      Observable.create((observer: any) => {
            this.searchChangeObserver = observer;
        }).pipe(
            debounceTime(300),
            distinctUntilChanged(),
            map((value) => {
                this.searchFilterValue = value;
                this.query = { q: " some text" + this.searchFilterValue};
                return query;
            }),
            switchMap((query) => this.appservice.search(query)),
            tap((response) => this.projects = response.results;)
            )
            .subscribe();
```

Put this in one method. You can pass other functions as parameter and do more.

Comment: My question is how can I write both functions in common services?

Comment: I would make one method with parameter and Observable as return parameter and than subrscibe on it. You can use it anywhere

Comment: One method where?

Comment: why you don´t create a abstract BaseProject class and put the getProjectList into it? Other components inheritance from the base clase

Comment: @dfil Inheritance in not a recommended pattern and SwitchMap has nothing to do with sharing a service.

Answer (score 0):

[The recommended pattern](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#services-are-singletons) is to use a shared service that you inject into your components. Following is a quick example :

shared.service.ts

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class SharedService {

  constructor(
    private httpClient: HttpClient
  ) {}

  searchSomething (someUrl) {
    return this.httpClient.get(someUrl);
  }
}
```

first.component.ts

```
import { SharedService } from '../../../core/services/shared.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'first-component',
    templateUrl: 'first.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['first.component.scss']
})

export class FirstComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor (   
    private sharedService: SharedService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.sharedService.searchSomething('exampleUrl.com').subscribe(result => console.log(result));
  }
}
```

Just do the same in your second component or in your second service and don't forget to declare the Service in the providers of your AppModule.

Comment: he has an shared service appService. And still you musst subscribe, unsubscribe and map values foreach project component.

Comment: @dfil You are presuming that he is building an autocomplete search, which at no point he mentioned. Using SwitchMap where it is not needed can confuse him. And no, you don't necessarily need to manually subscribe/unsubscribe, as you can use the async pipe and leave angular manage the subscribing/unsubscribing.